# How does .gdb folder file structure work?

Tags: database, gis

I'm working on a data-driven landslide analytics system. For this I downloaded a world lithology map dataset (what types of rocks are in different parts of the world). I intend to process this and add it as a feature to my machine learning model.

The dropbox link for the data download is here (~1GB): https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vuowtebp9f1iud/LiMW_GIS%202015.gdb.zip?dl=0

I have no idea how this data is structured, however. After unzipping the file, it produces a directory with some files inside it (full list is at the end of this post).

```
(base) shreyj@Shreys-TPL480:~/dev/GLAS/Landslide-Prediction/data/lithology/LiMW_GIS 2015.gdb$ ls
a00000001.gdbindexes
a00000001.gdbtable
a00000001.gdbtablx
a00000001.TablesByName.atx
a00000002.gdbtable
a00000002.gdbtablx
a00000003.gdbindexes
a00000003.gdbtable
a00000003.gdbtablx
a00000004.CatItemsByPhysicalName.atx
a00000004.CatItemsByType.atx
a00000004.FDO_UUID.atx
a00000004.freelist
a00000004.gdbindexes
a00000004.gdbtable
a00000004.gdbtablx
a00000004.spx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByName.atx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByParentTypeID.atx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByUUID.atx
a00000005.gdbindexes
a00000005.gdbtable
a00000005.gdbtablx
a00000006.CatRelsByDestinationID.atx
a00000006.CatRelsByOriginID.atx
a00000006.CatRelsByType.atx
a00000006.FDO_UUID.atx
a00000006.gdbindexes
a00000006.gdbtable
a00000006.gdbtablx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByBackwardLabel.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByDestItemTypeID.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByForwardLabel.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByName.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByOriginItemTypeID.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByUUID.atx
a00000007.gdbindexes
a00000007.gdbtable
a00000007.gdbtablx
a00000009.gdbindexes
a00000009.gdbtable
a00000009.gdbtablx
a00000009.spx
gdb
GLiM_v1_1.lyr
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to view the file as a general folder. This file can be view using ArcGIS or qgis software. connect your database in the .gdb extension.